# Gate synthesis with parametrised precision

Tags: qiskit, gate-synthesis, solovay-kitaev-algorithm

I am wondering whether Qiskit (or other quantum program language) can perform gate synthesis with parametrised precision.

I tried with

`from qiskit.transpiler.passes.synthesis import SolovayKitaev`

But this package can only decompose to a sequence of Clifford+T gates.

What I am looking for is a method accepting an arbitrary gate set and an approximation parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The "method accepting an arbitrary gate" is a tricky part". There are methods with some set of gates that you might have to later translate with a further transpiler pass.

For the approximation part, take a look to [Approximate Quantum Compiler (AQC)](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/synthesis_aqc.html), included in Qiskit 0.36 (Terra 0.19, Apr 2022). I personally prefer to use it as a plugin with the [UnitarySynthesis](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.transpiler.passes.UnitarySynthesis.html) and configure it via `plugin_config`. In particular, you can set the optimizer (see the available ones [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.optimizers.html#local-optimizers)) and its parameters.

In the following example, consider [`SLSQP(maxiter)`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.optimizers.SLSQP.html). By changing `maxiter` you can extend the computation time in favor of more exact approximation:

1. Create a circuit with a random unitary (4 qubits in this case)

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
from qiskit.quantum_info.random import random_unitary

qc = QuantumCircuit(4)

qc.unitary(random_unitary(16, seed=0), [0,1,2,3])
original_matrix = Operator(qc).data
```

2. Take `UnitarySynthesis` and an optimizer (`SLSQP` in this case)

```
from qiskit.transpiler.passes.synthesis.unitary_synthesis import UnitarySynthesis
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SLSQP
```

3. Using the `aqc` plugin, set optimizer with different `maxiter`. By the way, you can put some basis in `basis_gates`, not an arbitrary basis tho:

   a. With `SLSQP(1)`, it takes 192ms in my laptop and the accumulated error is 78.

```
result = UnitarySynthesis(basis_gates=["rx", "ry", "rz", "cx"], method='aqc', plugin_config={"seed": 42, "optimizer": SLSQP(1)})(qc)

import numpy as np
approx_matrix = Operator(result).data
np.sum(np.abs(original_matrix - approx_matrix))
```

```
77.80895049882317
```

b. With `SLSQP(10)`, it takes 1.55s in my laptop and the accumulated error is 36.

```python
result = UnitarySynthesis(basis_gates=["rx", "ry", "rz", "cx"], method='aqc', plugin_config={"seed": 42, "optimizer": SLSQP(10)})(qc)
approx_matrix = Operator(result).data

np.sum(np.abs(original_matrix-approx_matrix))
```

```
35.63557540562521
```

c. With `SLSQP(100)`, it takes 13.9s in my laptop and the accumulated error is 4.

```
result = UnitarySynthesis(basis_gates=["rx", "ry", "rz", "cx"], method='aqc', plugin_config={"seed": 42, "optimizer": SLSQP(100)})(qc)
approx_matrix = Operator(result).data

np.sum(np.abs(original_matrix-approx_matrix))
```

```
4.048035307578057
```

Answer (score 0):

BQSKit can do this exactly. You will need to calculate the unitary of your gate, and you can just plug that into its `compile` function.

You can accomplish this with the following:

```
from bqskit import compile, MachineModel
from bqskit.ir.gates import CZGate, U3Gate # import the gates you want to use
model = MachineModel(number_qubits, gate_set={CZGate(), ...})  # Define your desired gateset
output_circuit = compile(gate_unitary_input, model, synthesis_epsilon=1e-8)
```

In the above code snippet, you define the desired gate set inside of a `MachineModel` object and then compile your gate into a circuit. The resulting solution will be at most `synthesis_epsilon` away from the target unitary. You may also need to set the `max_synthesis_size` parameter in the `compile` call if your input is larger than 3 qubits.

For more info, you can refer to the BQSKit [documentation](https://bqskit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [tutorial](https://github.com/BQSKit/bqskit-tutorial).